# Different multi match for each mapping in one query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have 4 different mappings: `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.

For mappings `A` and `B` the following query gives best results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "....",
                    "analyzer": "keyword",
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                    "fields": ["name*"]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

For `C` the following query gives best results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "....",
                    "analyzer": "simple",
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                    "use_dis_max": false, 
                    "fields": ["name*"]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And for `D` the following query gives best results:

```
{

  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "....",
                    "analyzer": "simple",
                    "fuzziness": 0,
                    "use_dis_max": false, 
                    "fields": ["name*"]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "....",
                    "analyzer": "simple",
                    "fuzziness": 3,
                    "fields": ["name*"]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I can make 3 separate queries and process the results but it turns out to be messy and takes longer. Is it possible to combine these 3 queries into one and say for mapping/types `A` and `B` use the first multi match for `C` use the second and for `D` use the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with below using [Type Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-type-query.html).

For sake of simplicity I've only considered queries for type `C` and `D` as mentioned in the question.

Note that I've also included `boost` parameter and I've mentioned it in such a way that documents of type `C` would always appear higher in results as compared to documents of type `D`.

You can go ahead and make changes according to your requirements.

### Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "boost":100,
                  "must":[  
                     {  
                        "multi_match":{  
                           "query":"....",
                           "analyzer":"simple",
                           "fuzziness":"AUTO",
                           "use_dis_max":false,
                           "fields":[  
                              "name*"
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "type":{  
                           "value":"C"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "boost":5,
                  "must":[  
                     {  
                        "type":{  
                           "value":"D"
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "multi_match":{  
                           "query":"....",
                           "analyzer":"simple",
                           "fuzziness":0,
                           "use_dis_max":false,
                           "fields":[  
                              "name*"
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "multi_match":{  
                           "query":"....",
                           "analyzer":"simple",
                           "fuzziness":3,
                           "fields":[  
                              "name*"
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: hello, did the above solution help? Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Hi yes it did help thank you very much I just forgot to upvote/accept it.